# Regex password containing two separate digits

Tags: javascript, regex, passwords

In javascript

at least eight characters, of which two SEPARATE digits,

one uppercase and one lowercase letter as well as

one special character(-, @, #, $, &, *, +) Not /, !,? or "

Have tried many things, can not get at least 2 digits separated

started with

```
/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[-@#$&*+]).{8,}([^\/!?"])$/
```

tried with variations of

```
(?=.*\d(?!\d))

(?=.*(?<!\d)\d)
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About the patterns that you tried

- This pattern `(?=.*\d(?!\d))` matches a digit not directly followed by a digit
- This pattern `(?=.*(?<!\d)\d)` matches a digit not directly preceded by a digit

But both patterns do not make sure that there actually are 2 digits

---

You can assert a digit, at least 1 non digit and then again a digit.

As you don't want to match any of this character class `[^\/!?"]` you can omit it from the pattern, and only match the allowed characters, as the `.` matches any character.

```
 ^(?=.*\d[^\d\n]+\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[-@#$&*+])[-@#$&*+\dA-Za-z]{8,}$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?=.*\d[^\d\n]+\d)` Assert 2 separate digits
- `(?=.*[a-z])` Assert a char a-z
- `(?=.*[A-Z])` Assert a char A-Z
- `(?=.*[-@#$&*+])` Assert one of the characters that are considered special
- `[-@#$&*+\dA-Za-z]{8,}` Match 8 or more times any of the allowed characters
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QiGVmd/1)

Or a variant using [contrast](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-style.html#contrast) with [negated character classes](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated):

```
^(?=.*\d[^\d\n]+\d)(?=[^a-z\n]*[a-z])(?=[^A-Z\n]*[A-Z])(?=[^-@#$&*+\n]*[-@#$&*+])[-@#$&*+\dA-Za-z]{8,}$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cNFmQZ/1)